# clone() method (Shallow or Deep copying)

Tags: java, clone

In java books and online tutorials it is stated that `Object.clone()` method provides shallow copying unless Cloneable interface is used but in the code I implemented `clone()` method without using `Cloneable` interface and it is providing a deep copy instead of a shallow copy.

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
public class test1 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // create a gregorian calendar, which is an object
      GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

      // clone object cal into object y
      GregorianCalendar y = (GregorianCalendar) cal.clone();

      // check if reference of y is equal to cal or not
      System.out.println(cal==y);//it's output should be true if this is a shallow copy but it is false.
   }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy

Comment: A clone is a *different object,* so `==` will always evaluate to false.

Comment: since clone method is said to generate shallow copy, then it should copy references i.e.,== should evaluate to true for two objects as their references would be same

Comment: `GregorianCalendar` does implement the `Cloneable` interface, so it should make a deep copy.

Comment: @rcosteira now i get it why it was generating a deep copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GregorianCalendar` does implement the `Cloneable` interface, so it should make a deep copy.

Edit: Java deals with references to objects only. So, in this case, since `GregorianCalendar`'s `clone` method performs a deep copy, a way to copy the reference would be by assigning `cal` to `y`, i.e., `y = cal`.

Comment: could you please explain how to use clone() method to create shallow copy

Comment: @Sc00by_d00 you create a shallow copy in your clone() implementation by simply returning `super.clone()`. You create a deep copy by calling `super.clone()` *and then* calling `clone()` on all fields.